# CGAN not getting conditioned properly. How to start debugging?

Tags: machine-learning, gan

So I was trying to condition some images (10 classes) on corresponding EEG signals. However after traing, the CGAN is producing decent looking images but the images being produced simply do not correspond to the class whose conditioning was given.
What could be the possible culprits to this problem and what should i look into to fix this problem? Do you think it this is not very likely and there is a high chance of error in my code logic itself if this happening?

Comment: Hi @Maurya, welcome to the site. It is difficult to tell with that little information. You can overfit to a single batch to check if the generator can properly generate the conditioned images.

Answer (score 2):

While you haven't provided much information on the problem there could be several reasons why the CGAN is producing images that do not correspond to the class conditioning. Some common possible culprits to consider are:

- **Training Data Quality:** The quality and diversity of the training data can significantly impact the performance of the CGAN. If the training data is not representative of the classes or lacks diversity, the CGAN may struggle to generate accurate images for each class.
- **Model Architecture and Hyperparameters:** The architecture and hyperparameters of the CGAN, including the structure of the generator and discriminator networks, the learning rate, and the choice of loss functions, can influence the quality of the generated images.
- **Data Augmentation Techniques:** The use of appropriate data augmentation techniques, especially for EEG signals, can play a crucial role in improving the performance of the CGAN.
- **Distribution Mismatch:** If the distribution of the generated images differs significantly from the distribution of the real images, it can lead to discrepancies in the class conditioning.
- **Label Conditioning:** The effectiveness of the label conditioning process in the CGAN can impact the generation of class-specific images.

**Likelihood of Error in Code Logic**

Given the complexity of training a CGAN and the potential factors contributing to the issue, it is not unlikely that there could be errors in the code logic itself. However, it's important to systematically investigate the aforementioned culprits and potential solutions before attributing the issue solely to code logic.